# Visitors stats for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What is the best way to provide information who is using visiting blogs on wordpress installation? Is there a plugin that provides this information?

Answer (score 1):

Beside integrating Google Analytics, you should install the [WordPress.com Stats](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/) Plugin. To use it, you have to get a free "Wordpress.com" API Key, but then you can get very good details about the real visitors of your blog. It is not as huge as Google Analytics but it is a very good combination of what a blog user want's to know.

Comment: I've used the Google Analytics for WordPress Plugin (http://yoast.com/wordpress/google-analytics/#utm_source=wordpress&utm_medium=plugin&utm_campaign=google-analytics-for-wordpress) to integrate the Google Analytics Account ID into my WordPress blog.

Comment: Ah and if you also want to track the RSS feed stats, I can recommend the FeedStats Plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedstats-de/).

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) provides this kind of information. This [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analyticator/) integrates analytics reporting in to your WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics for WordPress is a great plugin. You can then get the analytics data from Google or other sites

http://roderickbarnes.com/blog/bif-analytics

I also suggest trying out the WordPress.com plugin: Jetpack. It is good stuff. It is also not recognized as a standard and hence should be viewed as outside of the mainstream.

Comment: Hi Roderick, thanks for the hint, your blog entry looks very interesting. However, please note that accounts whose only contribution to the site seems to be promoting a web site are in great danger of being classified as spam and the user account deleted by moderators, even though the answers are perfectly on-topic. See e.g. [Why my account is not there?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95234)